# HttpGetAttribute Order is ignored

Tags: c#, api, .net-6.0

I have two methods in a .net6 web API that I want to expose that have similar routes.
This should not be a problem since one has the keyword ping to identify the route.
But from the looks of it and also from the documentation, the route stops evaluating routes as soon as it finds a match.
As the code runs by default it picks the `GetDays` method instead of `Ping`. Most likely because it is found first.
This should be easy to resolve by adding an order to the route.
By default, the route should get order 0 so by setting -1 the `Ping` route should be evaluated first. And if it does not match try next.

But it does not work. It seems that the `Order` attribute is ignored and it still picks the `GetDays` method.

```
    [HttpGet("[controller]/ping", Order = -1)]  
    public async Task<IActionResult> Ping([FromQuery] string val)


    [HttpGet("{from}/{to}")]  
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetDays(DateTime from, DateTime to)
```

Anyone have any tips on why the `Order` attribute is ignored and how to make this work?

Comment: Why is your route not `[HttpGet("[controller]/{from}/{to}")]` ?

Comment: What is the client sending?  The route is coming from the client URL and the controller has to parse the URL to determine which method to call.  A default would be the URL without the method (like ping).  If the route matches from/to then the GetDays will be executed.